# Url routing and actionmethod relation - asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

If I want to make url like this:

```
www.site.com/UK/London/Jobs/98767
```

Routing url is like:

```
...
"{countryCode}/{city}/Jobs/{jobId}"
...
```

So here I need 4 parameters to build this url.
Should I have all this four parameters in actionmethod whenever I call it?

Comment: It' really easy to find out writing the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're registering your route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{countryCode}/{city}/Jobs/{jobId}}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Jobs"}
);
```

Your action would need 3 parameters:

```
public ActionResult Jobs(string countryCode, string city, int jobId)
{
    ...
}
```

The 3rd parameter "Jobs" is used for matching the route and doesn't make sense to pass in as a parameter.